# Flutter Devtool , Bad state: Missing key "isPubliclyHosted" when trying to parse DevToolsExtensionConfig object

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i try to open the devtool in flutter vs code the following error shows and widget tree is hidden

Unable to connect to VM service at ws://127.0.0.1:55302/
fvErkebdBCO=/ws: Bad state:
Missing key "isPubliclyHosted" when trying to parse
DevToolsExtensionConfig object.,
Bad state: Missing key
"isPubliclyHosted" when trying to parse DevToolsExtensionConfig object.

flutter version -
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, Xcode update (just updating it from App Store) solved the issue. Since I have not updated it for a while, it was disabled to launch Xcode, which might cause this error.